# Email OTP Verification in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, email-validation, one-time-password, email-verification

I am student and working on my university **final year project**. It requires to sign up with a verification of email.

I have tried **Java Mail** for send email with OTP code. I have used **google and outlook** emails but both of them **blocked/warned** me for sending spam mails, as All the mails have been sent from my email and it looks like spam.

I want to if there is any **free/cheap system for sending and verifying email to be used with android studio**. As I can't go with making new email again and again.

I have tried **Java Mail** for send email with OTP code. I have used **google and outlook** emails but both of them **blocked/warned** me for sending spam mails, as All the mails have been sent from my email and it looks like spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **Firebase Authentication**.

You have various verification options like Phone OTP, Email Link Verification and much more..
Follow the official website [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui).

Comment: Thanks. I am going to use email link verification provided by firebase. It is way far better than paid services.